# Ionic 5 - async in ion-content

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, async-pipe

I'm using a simple http get request in a service in an Ionic 5 application that returns an Observable. When I use that Observable with an async pipe inside ion-content in a template the ChangeDetection is not working on the data update of the Observable:

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="data$ | async as data>
    {{data.text}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

If I use the async pipe outside ion-content

```
  <div *ngIf="data$ | async as data>
    {{data.text}}
  </div>
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
```

the ChangeDetection works fine.

Is there anything (configuration?) I am missing?

Comment: Have you set the `onChangeDetection` to `onPush` somehow ?

Comment: No, as said, it works outside of ion-content

Comment: I did an update from ionic4 to ionic5?!

Comment: I haven't used Ionic 5 yet. Maybe you should submit an issue on Ionic's Github.